# replace li tag with different tag according to the bullet level

Tags: php, html, dom

need to replace the li tags with different customized tag according to the bullet level, For the li level1 keep it as is, for level2 change li to lii, for level3 change li to liii

For example for the input below (I have only 2 bullet levels in the below code just as example)

```
<p><strong>Basics to Macros & VBA Code</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>Create a Macro MsgBox
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test 1</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Workbook and Worksheet</li>
<li>Object Range</li>
<li>Object Variables</li>
<li>If Then Statement</li>
<li>Loop</li>
<li>Macro Errors</li>
<li>String Manipulation</li>
<li>Date and Time</li>
<li>Events</li>
<li>Array</li>
<li>Function and Sub</li>
<li>Application Object</li>
<li>Final Project</li>
</ul>
```

desired output

```
<p><strong>Basics to Macros & VBA Code</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>Create a Macro MsgBox
<ul>
<lii>test</lii>
<lii>test 1</lii>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Workbook and Worksheet</li>
<li>Object Range</li>
<li>Object Variables</li>
<li>If Then Statement</li>
<li>Loop</li>
<li>Macro Errors</li>
<li>String Manipulation</li>
<li>Date and Time</li>
<li>Events</li>
<li>Array</li>
<li>Function and Sub</li>
<li>Application Object</li>
<li>Final Project</li>
</ul>
```

as you can see the code should change only 2 lines (as it's level 2) and keep li level1 as is

```
<lii>test</lii>
<lii>test 1</lii>
```

my code in php

```
function clean($str)
{   
    $level = 0;
    $str_temp = $str;
    //$pos = strpos($str,"<ul>");
    $str1 = "";
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $str_temp) as $line){
        $line1 = "";
        if(strpos($line,"<ul>")){
            $level++;
        }elseif(strpos($line,"</ul>")){
            $level--;
        }
                
        if(level == 2){
            $str1 .= str_replace("<li>", "<lii>", $line1);
        }elseif(level == 3){
            $str1 .= str_replace("<li>", "<liii>", $line1);
        }else{
            $str1 .= $line1;
        }
    } 

    $str1 = trim($str1);
    return $str1;
}
```

**Update**

1- the html code is created by tinymce and stored in DB
2- I am using FPDF to output the DB to PDF file
3- I am using a specific library to FPDF to parse the html tags to have a specific style for each tag

Instead of devoting the questions, it's better if you try to help if you can, and keep it as is if you don't have anything to provide.

Comment: What's the reason for using different tags? Since `lii` and `liii` are invalid HTML tags.

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you want to achieve ultimately as there may be a better way. Is it just to layout the levels differently or is there some semantic reason underlying this?

Comment: @cbore it's really so sad from you to say that, because I am searching for help not a fight

Comment: @Reyno @A Haworth  I updated my question to give the reason of why I need this

Comment: If you need specific styling why not use a class? or just nested selectors `ul ul li`?

Comment: @Reyno the WriteTag library will parse only the html tags, also we will have several rows created by normal users by TinyMCE

Comment: I've also upvoted because now there is a description of why this needs to be achieved it is much clearer as a question.

Comment: Have you looked at PHP's DomDocument?

Comment: @AHaworth No I didn't check this, but I should to have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed my code and it works fine now, for the FPDF - witetag library purpose I removed the UL tags and closed each li tag at the end of the line, kept other tags as is.

```
function clean($str)
{   
    $str1 = "";
    $level = 0;
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $str) as $line){
        if(strpos($line,"<ul>") !== false ){
            $level++;
        }elseif(strpos($line,"</ul>")!== false){
            $level--;
        }
        
        if(strpos($line,"<li>")!== false){
            if(strpos($line,"</li>")=== false){
                $line = $line . "</li>";
            }
        }elseif(strpos($line,"</li>")!== false){
            $line = str_replace("</li>", "", $line);
        }else{
            $line= $line;
        }
        
        if($level == 2){
            $line = str_replace("<li>", "<lii>", $line);
            $line = str_replace("</li>", "</lii>", $line);
            $str1 .=  $line;
        }elseif($level == 3){
            $line = str_replace("<li>", "<liii>", $line);
            $line = str_replace("</li>", "</liii>", $line);
            $str1 .=  $line;
        }else{
            $str1 .= $line;
        }
        

    } 

    $str1 = str_replace("<ul>", "", $str1);
    $str1 = str_replace("</ul>", "", $str1);

    $str1 = trim($str1);
    return $str1;
}
```